# Loading bashrc via ssh login

Tags: ssh, bash

This command is referenced on this guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

```
# .profile
if [ -n "$BASH" ] && [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

What is the first `.`  on `. ~/.bashrc`?
Is it referencing my current directory and then home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"." is equivalent of `source` in bash.

A dot in this context means to "source" the contents of `.bashrc` into the current shell

```
. ~/.bashrc -> source ~/.bashrc
```

For more details read this: [source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html)

Comment: What is the difference in running" sh testscript.sh " vs  " . testscript.sh  " then?  They seem to behave the same.

Comment: I guess sh specifies the shell while . or source is a way of just signaling whatever current shell executes the script.